# When I include a sprite in a collision the sprite loses interactive property?

Tags: javascript, html, collision, phaser-framework

I want the 'kiwi' sprite to collide with the spikes group to trigger a game reset, but when
this collision *this.physics.add.collider(spikes, kiwi);* was created, the kiwi could no longer be controlled with arrow keys when it could previously - without being part of a collision.
Am I doing the collision wrong, or is there an issue with the sprite properties?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Kiwibird stuck in Japan</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.11.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;

    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
      type: Phaser.AUTO,
      width: 800,
      height: 600,
      
      physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
          gravity: {
            y: 300
          },
          debug: false
        }
      },
      
      scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
      }
    };
var spikes;
    var spiked = false;
    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    function preload() {
      this.load.image('japanbkrd', 'assets/japanbkrd.jpg');
      this.load.spritesheet('kiwi', 'assets/kiwi.png', {
        frameWidth: 56,
        frameHeight: 63
      });
      this.load.image('stone', 'assets/stone.png');
      this.load.image('smallstone', 'assets/smallstone.png');
            this.load.image('vertstone', 'assets/vertstone.png');
      this.load.image('halfstone', 'assets/halfstone.png');
      this.load.image('spike', 'assets/spike.png');
    }

    function create()
    //backround
    {
      this.add.image(400, 300, 'japanbkrd');
      //sprite
      player = this.physics.add.sprite(30, 450, 'kiwi');
      player.setBounce(0.1);
      player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
      cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

      var block = this.physics.add.image(200, 400, 'smallstone').setScale(.3)
          .setImmovable(true)
          .setVelocity(100, -100);
        block.body.setAllowGravity(false);

      //platforms
      platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
      platforms.create(45, 560, 'stone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(137, 560, 'stone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(413, 560, 'stone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(505, 560, 'stone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(597, 560, 'stone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(689, 560, 'stone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(781, 560, 'stone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      this.physics.add.collider(player, platforms);
      platforms.create(79, 411, 'vertstone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(45, 465, 'stone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(175, 430, 'smallstone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(260, 510, 'smallstone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(355, 525, 'vertstone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(355, 525, 'vertstone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(355, 433, 'vertstone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(355, 341, 'vertstone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(355, 249, 'vertstone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(45, 285, 'stone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(137, 285, 'stone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(229, 285, 'stone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
platforms.create(280, 400, 'smallstone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(337, 330, 'halfstone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(120, 196, 'smallstone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(250, 150, 'stone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(210, 150, 'stone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
platforms.create(45, 107, 'stone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(450, 258, 'vertstone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(450, 166, 'vertstone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();
      platforms.create(450, 74, 'vertstone').setScale(.3).refreshBody();


     spikes = this.physics.add.group();
      spikes.create(200, 200, 'spike').setScale(.8).setBounce(0)
this.physics.add.collider(spikes, platforms);
 this.physics.add.collider(spikes, kiwi); 
      
      this.tweens.timeline({
          targets: block.body.velocity,
          loop: -1,
          tweens: [
            { x:    200, y: 400, duration: 5000, ease: '' },
            { x:    300, y:    400, duration: 5000, ease: '' },
          ]
});
      this.anims.create({
        key: 'left',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('kiwi', {
          start: 0,
          end: 5
        }),
        frameRate: 10,
        repeat: -1
      });
      this.anims.create({
        key: 'turn',
        frames: [{
          key: 'kiwi',
          frame: 4
        }],
        frameRate: 20
      });
      this.anims.create({
        key: 'right',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('kiwi', {
          start: 6,
          end: 11
        }),
        frameRate: 10,
        repeat: -1
      });
    }

    function update() {
      
      if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(-100);
        player.anims.play('left', true);
      } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(100);
        player.anims.play('right', true);
      } else {
        player.setVelocityX(0);
        player.anims.play('turn');
      }
      if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down) {
        player.setVelocityY(-230);

      }
      if (spiked) {
    game.state.start(game.state.current);
  }
  
  spiked = false;
    }
    
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line of code,

```
 this.physics.add.collider(spikes, kiwi);
```

since `kiwi` doesn't exist, it should be `player`, the correct line would be this

```
 this.physics.add.collider(spikes, player);
```

The error cause the appliaction to stop.